# How do I create a domain from an array created using push to flatten an array created via .rollups?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, flatten

I'm a hacker so excuse this possibly dumb question:

How do I create a domain from an array created using push to flatten an array created via .rollups?

The original data was like this:

> ```
> (21664) […]
>
> [0…999]
>
> [0…99]
>
> 0: Object { Case_Reported_Date: "2021-03-23", Age_Group: "20s", Client_Gender: "UNSPECIFIED", … }
>
> 1: Object { Case_Reported_Date: "2021-03-23", Age_Group: "50s", Client_Gender: "FEMALE", … }
> ```

After rollups:

> ```
> (14) […]
>
> 0: (2) […]
>
> 0: Date Tue Mar 23 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
>
> <prototype>: Date.prototype { … }
>
> 1: (3) […]
>
> 0: Array [ "Not Resolved", 706 ]
>
> 1: Array [ "Resolved", 1 ]
>
> 2: Array [ "Fatal", 1 ]
>
> length: 3
>
> <prototype>: Array []
>
> length: 2
> ```

flatData (created using push)

> ```
> (14) […]
>
> 0: Object { count1: 706, outcome1: "Not Resolved", count2: 1, … }
>
> 1: Object { count1: 1561, outcome1: "Not Resolved", count2: 16, … }
> ```

When I attempt to create a domain from flatData it freezes. The reason for this is that I want to create a grouped bar chart. There may be a better way to do that so let me know if you have one.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or snippet with a data and D3 code?

Comment: I figured out what my problem was ... I had got the incorrect idea that I needed pure arrays for domains which wasn't correct. Using an array (flatData) with variables in an object was what I needed. Thanks for offering to help. Once I used the correct variable names worked:  y.domain([0, d3.max(flatData, function(d) {return d.count1;})]);